# Determine how many items in a while Loop

Tags: php, variables

How can I determine how many items there are in a while Loop?

**Example**:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){


echo "<strong>name:</strong> ".$row['name']."<br>";
echo "<strong>country:</strong> ".$row['country']."<br>";
echo "<strong>house:</strong> ".$row['house']."<br>";
}
```

**Output**:

Name: Example Name

Country: Germany

**House**: Example street 1

**House 2**: Example street 3

**House 3**: Example street 5

I need to know this because I want to add the number behind house 2/3 as a variable. Should I place the while loop in a for loop so I can add:

```
$housenumber++;

echo "<strong>house ".$housenumber.":</strong> ".$row['house']."<br>";
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
$total = mysql_num_rows($query);
```

To find out the **total** number of rows in the while loop.

Declare this before your while loop and after `$query` is defined.

However, I should point out that `mysql_query` and `mysql_num_rows` are deprecated and you should use MySQLi or PDO. See [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-db-query.php) for more information.

Comment: I pull data out of 2 databases so this gives me 1, when there are 3 houses registered. I actually just want to increment the number behind house with 1 every time it occur

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping a loop inside a loop won't accomplish what you're getting at (or it might, but it's just needless overkill). Incrementing a variable works in any kind of loop, so you could just write:

```
$housenumber = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
  echo "<strong>name:</strong> ".$row['name']."<br>";
  echo "<strong>country:</strong> ".$row['country']."<br>";
  echo "<strong>house ".$housenumber.":</strong> ".$row['house']."<br>";
  $housenumber++;
}
```

As Tom is saying you're using deprecated functions to retrieve MySQL data, so your code will cease to work in future versions of PHP.

Comment: Thank you thisw works. And thank you for the tip about MySQL/MySQLi good to know!